# Using a variable in two different methods

Tags: android

Am trying to use jsoup library in my android application and i want to get the value of str1 in the description class and use it in MyAdapter class as items.add(new Item(str1, R.drawable.flag_one)); i can't figure it out, any help is highly appreciated

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

// URL Address
String url = "http://www.livescore.com";

public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    getOverFlowMenu();

    GridView gridView = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(rootView.getContext()));

    new Description();

    return rootView;

}

private void getOverFlowMenu() {

}

//Description async task
class Description extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    String desc;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try{
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            Element content = document
                    .body().getElementsByClass("kubrick-info__title").first();
            // Locate the content attribute
            desc = content.text();

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        // Set description into TextView
        String str1 = desc;
    }
}

private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context)
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        items.add(new Item(str1, R.drawable.flag_one));
        items.add(new Item("teams", R.drawable.flag_two));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i)
    {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i)
    {
        return items.get(i).drawableId;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can you declare `static String str1 = ""` at the top, right under `public class HomeFragment extends Fragment`? Then in your `onPostExecute` method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
    // Set description into TextView
    str1 = desc;
}
```

The idea is that if it the String is declared at the top, it will be visible throughout the entire `HomeFragment` class.

Comment: Where are you getting the exception? Could you give more information?

Comment: When i run the code it picks up the first str1 and therefore shows nothing

Comment: Try setting your adapter in the onPostExecute method.